# How to view all globals in any given JavaScript environment?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'd like to discover all globals which exist in the current JavaScript environment, whether that environment is a browser, Node.js, Deno, etc.

I have tried enumerating the properties of the `globalThis` and `window` objects, but they don't reveal everything.

As an example, in a browser (Chrome v83), logging `Object.keys('window')` does not yield the `DOMParser` or `XMLSerializer` interfaces, yet I can instantiate a `new DOMParser()`.

How can I programmatically get a list of all globals while in the environment, without needing to reference some kind of external documentation?

Comment: I don't think you can. They don't show up in Object.keys because they're not necessarily enumerable properties.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. That was very helpful feedback.

Comment: There also the issue that variables declared with `const` or `let` are not properties of the global object. Trying to find them by inspection of global properties is doomed before you start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As @Barmar pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925611/how-to-view-all-globals-in-any-given-javascript-environment#comment109527530_61925611), in order to see everything, [non-enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) must also be included:

```js
const caseInsensitiveSort = (a, b) => {
  const lowerA = a.toLowerCase();
  const lowerB = b.toLowerCase();
  if (lowerA < lowerB) return -1;
  if (lowerA > lowerB) return 1;
  return 0;
};

const sortedGlobals = [...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globalThis)].sort(caseInsensitiveSort);

console.log(sortedGlobals);
```